# undefined reference to 'uuid_generate@UUID_1.0

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am installing apache on my ubuntu16.04, and the problem "/usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'" occurs when I do "sudo make"

I tried nm /usr/local/lib/libuuid.so | grep uuid_generate

The result is:
0000000000001a30 T uuid_generate

and nm /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.so | grep uuid_generate

The result is:
U uuid_generate@@UUID_1.0

so the problem may be the version of the libuuid? But I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Source https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/issues/131

> It might be possible that this error has is related to a broken Python
>   installation. If you are conda, try deactivating the conda or switch
>   to a stable version of Python.